# How to ssh to only 1 out of 3 routers if the router active and visible in python

Tags: python, json, networking, ssh

I have 3 routers and at one time i just need to ssh to only any 1 of 3 routers and run some command. For now my code will ssh to all 3 routers.
I just need to ssh to only 1 active router.

Scenario
First check 1st router if alive and if alive..proceed to ssh to 1st router and run command..end..but... if 1st router down and not visible to the network try check 2nd router and if alive..proceed to ssh to 2nd router and run command..end...if down...check for 3rd router...and if all down give notification.

I'm using netmiko to ssh to the devices.

This is the code to ssh to all the devices:-

```
with open('routers.json') as dev_file:
  devices = json.load(dev_file)


for device in routers['router']:
  try:
    print('Connecting to device:', device['ip'])
    connection = netmiko.ConnectHandler(**device)
    if  device['device_type'] == "cisco_ios" :
        output = net_connect.send_command("show arp")
        print(output)
```

This is routers.json file:-

```
{
  "router": [
    {
        "device_type": "cisco_ios",
        "ip": "192.168.100.10",
        "password": "cisco123",
        "username": "user1"
    },
    {
        "device_type": "cisco_ios",
        "ip": "192.168.100.20",
        "password": "cisco123",
        "username": "user1"
    },
    {
        "device_type": "cisco_ios",
        "ip": "192.168.100.30",
        "password": "cisco123",
        "username": "user1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Just need to ssh to only 1 out of 3 routers if active and reliable. Please assist further. Thank you

** Add break statement if found router up. If not continue to check other routers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a function to check if the IP is pingable, we can use `os.system` to run `ping` command on the IP, and if we can ping the IP, we can connect it

```
def check_ping(ip_address):

    response = -1

    #Check if we can ping the IP, if we can, response will be 0,
    try:
        response = os.system("ping -c 1 {}".format(ip_address))
    except Exception as exc:
        pass

    if response == 0:
        host_is_up = True
    else:
        host_is_up = False

    return host_is_up
```

Using that function, we can rewrite the code as

```
import os

#Open devices file
with open('routers.json') as dev_file:
  devices = json.load(dev_file)

#Function to check if ip address is pingable
def check_ping(ip_address):

    response = -1

    #Check if we can ping the IP, if we can, response will be 0,
    try:
        response = os.system("ping -c 1 {}".format(ip_address))
    except Exception as exc:
        pass

    if response == 0:
        host_is_up = True
    else:
        host_is_up = False

    return host_is_up

for device in routers['router']:
    try:
        #If device_type matches cisco_ios, do stuff
        if device['device_type'] == "cisco_ios":
            print('Connecting to device:', device['ip'])
            if check_ping(device['ip']):
                connection = netmiko.ConnectHandler(**device)
                output = net_connect.send_command("show arp")
                print(output)
    #Added the missing except
    except:
        pass
```

The output will look like

```
Connecting to device: 192.168.100.10
.....
```

Comment: Hi sir... first of all thanks for your response. fyi device_type cannot be change as this is part of netmiko module for cisco device the device_type must be set as 'cisco_ios'  the only different is the ip address of each router. Actually 3 routers here is for redundancy purpose... maybe all 3 router active and up...but and at one time i just need to access only 1 of them...not all...for example...if router 192.168.100.10 active and up...so ssh to this router... and no need to ssh to the rest of the router...

Comment: How do you decide which one you need access to? Is it at random? Do you know the ip beforehand you can match against?

Comment: To the first router that active/up....if the 1st router (192.168.100.10) up (can ping) then ssh to 1st router.... the IP is already fix in the disct file.

Comment: So that is a property of connection object, if I cannot ping the ip, does the netmiko connecthandler function throw an exception? Or is there a property in connection object you can check to ensure ip is pingable?

Comment: Im thinking something like...ping the IP (the IP address from dict file) first...if first IP can ping...thn proceed wth ssh process. Just the ping part here...not sure how to handle it

Comment: Sure, I would use a `ping` system call to check if the IP is up or not, I added a sample function for it, you can perhaps expand on it @chenoi

Comment: Let me run and test it...will update later...thanks

Comment: Sure, if it works for you, Please consider accepting the answer @chenoi :) You can play around with the `check_ping` according to your needs!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192884/discussion-between-chenoi-and-devesh-kumar-singh).